# Email a graph generated with ASP

Tags: c#, email, razor, graph, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC4 application that I am working on and I am trying to find a way to generate a line graph that I can then send out in an email.

Clients are also going to be looking a graphs of similar data on a website and I would like to use the same tool for each (for visual consistency and maintenance).

I looked into using Microsoft Chart Controls, but I can't find any MVC4/Razor examples or tutorials.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: http://www.highcharts.com/ can generate an image from a generated graph.

Comment: I need to generate the graph on the server to email it.

Comment: Can you attach the graphs, or do they need to be embedded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the Microsoft chart controls have the ability to save the chart as a PNG file. You would need to save the chart and either embed it as part of an HTML-formatted message body or attach the image.

**some sample code**

This isn't much, but it should get you started.

```
var chart = new Chart
{
    Height = 300,
    Width = 500
};
chart.Legends.Add(new Legend());
chart.Series.Add(new Series());
chart.ChartAreas.Add(new ChartArea());
chart.Titles.Add(new Title());
chart.SaveImage(savePath);
```

Comment: Everything I can find on implementing MCC is in web forms, but I am using MVC 4.

Comment: You can work with the `System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting` library directly. You create a new `Chart` object. You add a `Series` (aka, your data) to it. You add a `Title`, etc. Finally, you call `chart.SaveImage(imageSavePath)` to write the file to disk. 

The solution works for anything .NET, as long as you have access to the `System.Web.UI.DataVisualization` library.

I don't have any non-proprietary code to share, sorry.

Comment: Thanks, I will start with that.

Comment: Thanks a ton, that is enough to get me going.